# Verify the Git Credentials supplied by the User

Tags: git

I am writing an application in which we will support git integration. The user will provide us with his git credentials so that we can push some files on his git.

The git credentials which user will supply can be

1. The Account URL, eg: https://github.com/OpenPrinting
2. HTTP (Username and Password/ Kerberos)
3. SSH

Before saving the user credentials I want to validate that the credentials entered is valid.

The user might be using GithHub/BitBucket/GitLab. I am trying to find some **git** command or some frameworks in **java** which I can use to validate the credentials. Can you please point me to some command/logic which I can try?

**What I have tried ?**
I tried `git ls-remote` command, but it requires the repo name/url. In one of our use case, the user won't specify the **repository name** or URL beforehand. Because of which I am not able to use this command.

Comment: For ssh, you can use `ssh -T git@server` without the repo name/url.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried git ls-remote command, but it requires the repo name/url. In one of our use case, the user won't specify the repository name beforehand. Because of which I am not able to use this command.

You must at least have the URL to test the credentials.

`git ls-remote` will take a URL. Use -h to limit the output.

`git ls-remote -h <url>`

All you need to check is the exit code.

Comment: The url is the url of the account( https://github.com/OpenPrinting) or repo (https://github.com/OpenPrinting/system-config-printer.git)

Comment: @DeepakPatankar You'd need the URL of a Git remote associated with their account. If it's https you'll also need credentials. If it's ssh you don't.

Comment: @DeepakPatankar There are Github/Gitlab/Bitbucket specific tricks you can do, but `git ls-remote <repo url>` will work for any Git repository.